# Linear algebra basis proof

Tags: linear-algebra

Suppose that $a_1,a_2,...,a_n$ form a basis of $\mathbb{R}^n$ and $y = c_1a_1 + c_2a_2 + ·· + c_na_n$ with $c_j = 0$. 
Prove that $a_1,\ldots,a_{j-1},y,a_{j+1},\ldots,a_n$ do not form a basis of $\mathbb{R}^n$.

I am not sure how to approach this problem. I could not even understand the problem definition. Looks like it is saying $y=0$ to describe it is linearly independent.

Comment: Welcome to MSE! I have edited your post to make it more readable. [Here](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5020/144766) is a MathJax tutorial.

Comment: Thanks, i have not used it before, so i didn't know.

Comment: The $j$-th coefficient $c_j$ is $0$, but not the other $c_i$'s, so we don't have $y=0$.

Comment: try to write down a concrete instance of your problem where you replace the yariables by numbers and vectors, e.g n=3, a1=(1,0,0), ..., maybe tha helps you to understand the problem.

Comment: @Gribouillis that's what i was confused, thanks. still having problem to prove though.

Answer (score 0):

To form a basis in $\mathbb{R}^n$ you need at least $n$ linearly independent vectors. The question gave you $n-1$ linearly independent vectors (with $a_j$ excluded) plus another vector $y$ whose definition was also given. To show that they do not form a basis in $\mathbb{R}^n$, you must show that $y$ is not linearly independent from the $n-1$ vectors. How would you do that?

Answer (score 0):

The set $\{a_1,\ldots,a_{j-1},y,a_{j+1},\ldots,a_n\}$ is not linearly independent:

$$-c_1a_1 +\ldots - c_{j-1}a_{j-1} + \underbrace{1}_{\ne 0}\cdot y -c_{j+1}a_{j+1} - \cdots -c_{n}a_n = 0$$

We have found a linear combination of $a_1,\ldots,a_{j-1},y,a_{j+1},\ldots,a_n$ equal to $0$ such that not all scalars are $0$.

Thus, $\{a_1,\ldots,a_{j-1},y,a_{j+1},\ldots,a_n\}$ cannot be a basis for $\mathbb{R}^n$.